# access through thread

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, jtable

In the following code I've created a JTable in class main and I'm starting a thread to collect some value. I want that value to be updated in the JTable shown in the window(i.e. the JTable of class main). Actually I want "a" in the at (0,0) in the following code to change to "new value" at (0,0) after I run this code.

Please Help.

**Test.java**

```
package test;

import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;
import java.awt.*;


public class Test implements ActionListener {
Thread t;
JTable table;
JScrollPane scrollPane;
JButton b;
JFrame frame;
public void body() {
    frame = new JFrame("TableDemo");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    table = new JTable(new MyTableModel());
    table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(500, 70));
    table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
    scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
    frame.add(scrollPane);
    b = new JButton("OK");
    frame.add(b);
    thread a = new thread(new MyTableModel());
    t = new Thread(a);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    b.addActionListener(this);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Test().body();
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    t.start();
}
}

class MyTableModel extends AbstractTableModel
{
    private String[] columnNames = {"First Name",
                                    "Last Name",
                                    "Sport"};
    private Object[][] data = {
    {"a", "a","a"}
    };

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return columnNames.length;
    }

    public int getRowCount() {
        return data.length;
    }

    public String getColumnName(int col) {
        return columnNames[col];
    }

   public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
       return data[row][col];
   }
   public Class getColumnClass(int c) {
       return getValueAt(0, c).getClass();
   }
   public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) {
       if (col < 3) {
           return false;
       } else {
           return true;
       }
   }
   public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int col) {

        data[row][col] = value;
       fireTableCellUpdated(row, col);
    }
}
```

**thread.java**

```
package test;

public class thread implements Runnable {
    MyTableModel model;
    thread(MyTableModel model)
    {
        this.model = model;

    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
    Object aa = "new value";
    this.model.setValueAt(aa, 0, 0);
    System.out.println(this.model.getValueAt(0, 0));
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you should pass to the thread constructor the tableModel that is attached to the grid, not a new one:

```
MyTableModel model = new MyTableModel();
table = new JTable(model);
...
thread a = new thread(model);
t = new Thread(a);
```

And Swing components are not thread-safe, so their use must always be done by the event dispatch thread. To update the cell, the thread must do something like this:

```
final Object aa = "new value";
SwingUtilites.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        model.setValueAt(aa, 0, 0);
        System.out.println(model.getValueAt(0, 0));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Please pass the right `MyTableModel` to your thread and not a new one

```
MyTableModel model = new MyTableModel();
...
table = new JTable(model);
...
thread a = new thread(model);
```

Otherwise you will set your value in a completely other object.

It looks not like a threading problem. If this does not work, please try if this does work when you call

```
t.run();
```

instead of

```
t.start()
```

By the way: find a better name for your class and let it start with an upper case letter as suggested by the [Java Coding Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html)

Comment: Sorry. That was by mistake.
I've corrected that. But my this is not working as I want it to.

Comment: What does `System.out.println(this.model.getValueAt(0, 0));` tell you?

Comment: new value.
but this is not reflecting in the actual JTable been shown to the user. It is only changing the value of data model passed to it. And not in the data model of the class main.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to access the model from another thread as swing is not thread safe.  See [this](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/threads/threads1.html)